# Hiding text for an image gallery - SEO implications

Tags: jquery, seo, photo-gallery

So i've created a dynamic photo gallery using jquery. Its basically a large image with accompanying descriptive text to the right and a film strip running across the bottom. I structured the filmstrip so that each thumbail is accompanied by its hidden descriptive text and jquery udpates the main text area with the hidden text when the thumbnail is clicked.

I did all this before looking into SEO techniques and now am unsure if this technique could penalize me. I really don't want to have to redo everything. I've heard conflicting advice, some say hidden text is always bad, some say its the "intent" that matters.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the philosophy that it both "depends" and is really about "intent". For example, when you say that you have the descriptive text "hidden" it depends on what you mean by that. If you are using the images "alt" attribute and then pulling that with jQuery into a visual description - I see that as completely appropriate. If you are using hidden divs and then showing them onclick or something - it's not the cleanest solution, but I don't think it's going to bring you an penalties.

Comment: I'm using hidden divs. There are multiple fields for each picture (title, description, location, testimonial, etc). I'm starting to think it might be better to just add custom attributes and deal with my html being invalid.

Comment: Having hidden divs that are used and shown under certain conditions isn't something that the search engines would look down at. Just about every tabs script uses hidden divs to show the active tab and hide the others. I really don't see this as something you should worry to much about.